# Calculating average/median temperature per months

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table: in column A I have a (chronological) list of dates, in column B I have extracted months from dates and in column C I have an average temperature for every day.

I want to calculate mean, median and standard deviation for every month in the table. What is the quickest way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried?  There are standard Excel functions that can calculate those values; you could also consider a Pivot Table

Comment: Can you show an example of your Data and where you want the result?

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the daily averages for each day of a month, monthly Mean is easy to calculate. 
First record the daily mean temperature for the 
Month. 
Then find the monthly mean by adding daily means and dividing the sum by the number of days in the month.